# Hide flat shipping when free shipping is eligible in magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods, free-shipping

Do anyone know how to **hide flat shipping when free shipping is eligible** in magento 2.1?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is not default functionality. I can think of a few routes to address this issue.

- hack - use jQuery to detect free shipping loaded, hide flat shipping if so. I will note that you can finish the task quickly, but it will become very difficult in the future to keep track of. I recommend following more of a Magento-approved style.
- Override the template that displays that step in checkout. A quick look indicates that the relevant template is `vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/shipping.html`. So, you would [bring that template into your theme](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/templates/template-override.html) as described in the M2 docs.

It looks like the table is populated using the knockout.js framework. This is a bit more involved. To integrate with knockout you're gonna want to do some climbing up the learning curve, first. 1) [interactive beginning tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com) 2) [Alan Storm series](http://alanstorm.com/series/magento2-advanced-javascript/). But yeah, that's probably the most direct route: override the template and modify to suit your needs.

- Alternatively, you could get more tricky with knockout, or possibly with a [Magento interceptor](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html), in order to modify the template's behavior without overriding it.